# what type of encryption could be used

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a mysql table with a password column with the encrypted values in the following format:

```
1:zQtUZSG/lfWc246vxdjwkw==VQXjCwmKIkOLuhbb+37fYg==
```

I need to know what encryption is used and how I can decrypt this column. 
The encryption is done at the front end so could be done through java.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got access to the hybris DB then take a look at the p_passwordencoding field of the users table. This contains the encoding used for the password.

However, it's highly likely (almost a certainty) that this is a one way hash. So there's no real way to decode the password. In this case I'd set the password encoding to 'plain' and set the password to some plain text. You could then log in using this user and set the password appropriately in the hMC.